# Using jaxb/MOXy to map java classes to XML to be sent using Feign, is there any way to set Feign to use a custom JAXBContextFactory?

Tags: java, jaxb, soap-client, feign

I'm using  jaxb/MOXy to map my java classes to XML to be sent using Feign, is there any way to set a custom JAXBContextFactory to Feign so I can use @XmlPath provided by jaxb/Moxy? I only get the right mapping once I set the jaxb.properties with the content below:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```